# gcc 4.4 in Xcode

Tags: xcode, gcc, macos

how can I use the latest version of gcc installed from MacPorts in Xcode?

Comment: I have tried looking into Project setting, however I do not get any option other the system provided gcc 4, and 4.2
I generate my project using cmake, where I did tell it to use the gcc from macports

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can (easily). There are big differences between the Apple gcc compilers and mainline gcc. Perhaps if you explained *why* you think you need to use gcc 4.4 then there might be a better answer.

Comment: Becasue I want to use c++0X features

Comment: Probably the easiest thing would be to run a Linux distribution in a  VM under VMware Fusion or Parallels and then use that to play with gcc 4.4. Ceratainly a lot easier than trying to build and integrate gcc 4.4 with Xcode.